# How to stop iOS scrolling animation on clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ios

i'm facing an issue on iOS.

How to stop iOS scrolling animation on clicked.

i have a sidebar that on click show, when scrolling it's hide.
but in iOs when scroll animation is not ended, it can't show the div.

on default `.is-sort`, `.is-search`, `.is-filter` are hidden.

on click `.is-menu` then `.is-sort`, `.is-search`, `.is-filter` will show.

on scroll `.is-menu` then `.is-sort`, `.is-search`, `is-filter` will hide.

So any idea to make it work?

JS Below

```
$(".button.is-menu").click(function (e) {
    $(".a").removeClass("closed");

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".a").addClass("slide-in");
    }, 128);
});

$("#Content").scroll(function () {
    $(".a").removeClass("slide-in");

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".a").addClass("closed");
    }, 128);
});
```

HTML below

```
<div class="a closed">
    <button class="button is-cart">
        <i class="mdi mdi-cart"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="button is-sort">
        <i class="mdi mdi-sort"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="button is-search">
        <i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="button is-filter">
        <i class="mdi mdi-filter"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="button is-menu">
        <i class="mdi mdi-menu"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the animation on the `.a` class or the `.closed` and `.slide-in` classes? There is a period of time where neither slide-in or closed are on the `.a` element. I'm guessing during this period of time, closed is removed, the scroll is triggered, it removes slide-in, then slide-in is added by the first function, then closed is added by the second. I bet if you inspect element, both classes are on the element after clicking then scrolling. It's likely cascading the slide-in state.

Comment: For instance...
User clicks -> closed is removed -> user scrolls -> slide-in is removed -> slide-in is added -> closed is added.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I commented above, you can make sure you are resetting the state in your anonymous function like this:

```
    $(".a").removeClass("closed");

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".a").removeClass("closed").addClass("slide-in");
    }, 128);
});

$("#Content").scroll(function () {
    $(".a").removeClass("slide-in");

    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".a").removeClass("slide-in").addClass("closed");
    }, 128);
});
```

Adding extra removeClass's won't hurt anything, but will guarantee that the state is set correctly even if the user does something during the 128ms.